# How mailgun track opened emails?

Tags: email, gmail

1. I receive email sent through mailgun.
2. I open email (no info in mailgun log about opening email)
3. I allow displaying images ('opened' event in mailgun logs)

But what I do not understand: when I allow images then all requests go to google servers. How mailgun tracks it?

Comment: Off topic sorry, but I use mailgun which is a rackspace company.  They track the opening by allowing images to 'call home'. The image URLs are rewritten to call through rackspace servers. I can't remember if it's all or a few of them but that is how they track you.

Comment: In this context, this is off topic, however I ironically just had an on-topic question before this one in the close queue to which the answer to this is indirectly explained.  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/165320/is-my-computer-compromised/165360#165360

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email tracking is typically accomplished by embedding a transparent, 1x1 image in the body of the email message. The image is hosted externally at a unique URL controlled by Mailgun, so Mailgun can track whether the image has been downloaded.

It doesn't matter whether your browser/email client downloads the image, or whether Google downloads the image and sends it to your browser. In the end, in order to show the image *someone* has to download it which will trigger the tracking alert.

It is not a foolproof method, since users who disable fetching of remote content and don't opt to show images won't download the image as you've discovered. In the opposite direction, some email providers automatically visit all URLs in an email to scan for malware, so the tracker can trip even if the user has not opened the email.